# Non Native Raspberry Pi Camera

Tags: raspicam, pi-4, picamera

I am trying to set up [this](https://www.vision-components.com/en/products/oem-embedded-vision-systems/vc-mipi-camera-modules/) camera to my raspberry pi 4. The fact about this camera is that, according to the seller it's different than the normal v2 cameras that we typically install on raspberry pi and it needs some extra work. I followed the [instructions](https://www.vision-components.com/fileadmin/external/documentation/hardware/VC_MIPI_OV9281_Raspberry_PI_Model_3BPlus/index.html) from the seller in order to install the driver and etc. Everything went smoothly according to the instruction but I am not able to capture images from this camera when it is connected to my pi. Here are the kind of things that I did so far:

1. I checked all the connections of the camera and they seem okay.
2. I tried the picamera v2 module and it works fine but not the aforementioned camera.
3. I checked the raspi-config and the camera is enabled.
4. When I try the `raspistill` command, it throws the following exception

> mmal: Cannot read camera info, keeping the defaults for OV5647 mmal:
>   mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera'
>   (1:ENOMEM) mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create
>   component 'vc.ril.camera' (1) mmal: Failed to create camera component
>   mmal: main: Failed to create camera component mmal: Camera is not
>   detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed
>   correctly

5. I contacted their support team and they said you cannot use `raspistill` with this camera, that command is for the Picamera module. I have no idea what they mean by this.
6. I follow their instruction in [this](https://www.vision-components.com/fileadmin/external/documentation/hardware/VC_MIPI_OV9281_Raspberry_PI_Model_3BPlus/index.html) link without any problem but I am not sure how to capture an image without any error.
7. Any help would be appreciated and please let me know in the message box if I did not provide the full info. Also something to keep in mind, the seller informed me that this camera setup is different than the normal raspi camera that we typically use.

My final question is, if I am not supposed to use raspistill to capture images, then how can I capture images?

It might not be useful but I attach here the picture of the camera.[image: Picture of the Camera]

Comment: The linked documentation instructs how to compile and run the sample applications. Section 3.4 onwards should be followed closely.   Near the end of the document it says that the 'vcimgnetclient.py' python script can be used as the image client.  After following the previous instructions, I would check the operation of 'vcimgnetclient.py' if that works ok then study 'vcimgnetclient.py' to find out what you can possibly do to integrate it into other python programs.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation you linked to, this camera doesn't come with an application to capture images. They offer a demo application, written in C, but other than that you have to write your own application to utilize this camera.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if this question seems stupid but is there anyway to make python’s picamera to read from this camera?

Comment: @RAS: Most things are possible, but it's unlikely you're going to want to go that route. It would still involve a lot of custom C code and then pairing it with the existing library somehow.